# Sales monthly 2023 vs december 2022

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

I have a table with sales from 2021 to May 2023. I need to calculate the diference between sales in december 2002 versus sales in january 2023, february 2023 and so on. For example:

December 2022: 1000

January 2023: 1100-1000 = 100

February 2023: 1000-1000= 0

March 2023: 1200-1000 =200

I've used this dax measure with sales, and also calendar table, but it's not working fine:

```
**REAL VS DECEMBER =
VAR _Date =
    MAX ( 'sales'[date] )
VAR _DecV =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'sales'[amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( sales),
            YEAR ( 'sales'[date] )
                = YEAR ( _Date ) - 1
                && MONTH ( 'sales'[date] ) = 12
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUM ( sales[amount] ) - _DecV**
```

Result from the formula with sales and budget table, first two columns you can find sales and also budget

[image]